# SAS - Totaling values in a column by a different column's value

Tags: sas, dataset

The title may be a little ambiguous. Essentially, using the SASHELP.SHOES dataset, I'm trying to summarize the data in a new table by totaling the Sales, and Returns for each region. For instance, instead of having 56 rows for shoes sold in Africa and their individual sales/returns values, I have one row for Africa with columns TotalSales and TotalReturns. I need to do this for each region in the original dataset.

I'm not familiar at all with SAS, this is more or less the first thing I've really had to program in it. I've tried a few variations of data steps with IN or WHERE conditions, proc means steps with SUM() statements, and DO/DO WHILE loops, but I've missed something each time.

Comment: Did you try using PROC MEANS?

Comment: I did, but I don't have a great handle on the syntax for PROC MEANS. I believe I had Region as the variable to work off of, and then 'TotSales = sum(Sales);' but that didn't output anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

In `Proc MEANS`

- Use a `CLASS` statement to specify which variable(s) are to be used to group the data.  In your case `REGION`.
- Use the `VAR` statement to specify which variable(s) are to have statistics calculated for within each grouping.

**Default output**

Corresponding to the minimal syntax

```
ods listing;
proc means noprint data=SASHELP.SHOES;
   class region;
   var sales returns;
   output out=shoes_stats;
run;
```

Creates data set `WORK.SHOES_STATS` with one row per statistic per region.

[image]

**Other output structure**

- Use procedure option `NWAY` to only get summarizations for combinations of all the `CLASS` variables. (In your case this corresponds to rows with `_TYPE_=1`)
- The output columns can have the statistic name automatically concatenated to the variable name using the `OUTPUT` statement option `/ autoname`.
- Use data set options to control variables that are kept or dropped.

```
proc means nway noprint data=SASHELP.SHOES;
   class region;
   var sales returns;
   output out=shoes_sums(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum= / autoname;
run;

dm 'vt shoes_sums; column names' viewtable;
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! The only change I need is to avoid including TYPE, FREQ, and STAT. I just need a single row per Region with the total for Sales and Returns. i.e the row for Africa should just be: Africa        $2,232,588       $74,087. What would I need to alter to achieve that output?

Comment: Continue your reading of the documentation and you will learn about MEANS NWAY and AUTONAME features (answer updated to show example of their use)

Comment: Perfect, thank you again. Seeing a working example of MEANS NWAY is very helpful.